# Increase max transparency bounces past 1024

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am rendering a large grassy field with each grass blade being an alpha-clipped plane. I need to go past 1024 transparency bounces in Cycles but it won't let me and the grass looks black. How can I go past 1024 bounces?

Comment: You can't change that limit without modifying Blender's C code.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @Marty Fouts.

Comment: So what should I do? Is there an alpha clip alternative in cycles? (Because I know that that is an option in eevee.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you get further from the camera you need less detail, you can possibly get away with a very simple mesh and a particle emitter for the distant areas.

[image]

[image]

Another option is to render a bunch of your current grass to one image with a transparent background so that you're getting much more grass per transparent bounce, and then instance that in your scene.

Comment: Good idea. I think I'll try that.